# Is that a good idea to create a groupon like website using Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, groupon

I'm new to Angularjs. Now I'm going to create a groupon like website. So I checked lots of similar websites. None of them using the one-page style. So I'm thinking when to use Angularjs. Is that a good idea to create a groupon like website using Angularjs?

Comment: Did you end up pursuing this? If so please share the link so we can see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heck yea it is. The only thing is to keep the initial page load fast. So you might need to dynamically import your js files using something like: http://requirejs.org/